# sqlfiddle.com OpenId logon attempt fails

Tags: support, stack-exchange-openid

Attempting to logon to http://sqlfiddle.com using my stackexchange OpenId, I got the following error messsage:

> An error occurred on the server This event has been recorded.
>
> If you believe you encountered this message in error, please report
>   it.

I typed https://openid.stackexchange.com in the OpenId url box. It is correct?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This isn't really a Stack Overflow problem, but since you asked here I'll answer you here (next time, feel free to ping me on twitter @sqlfiddle or email me : admin at sqlfiddle dot com).

OpenID 2 (which is what I use currently at SQL Fiddle) is basically a dead technology. The current system I have is buggy and many of the providers I list aren't running any more.

I am in the midst of a complete re-write of the backend ( see progress here: https://github.com/jakefeasel/sqlfiddle2 ) which will switch this mechanism to use OpenID Connect instead. The good news is that this is the latest and greatest social login standard; the bad news is that there are not many Identity Providers (IDPs) currently running; basically, Google is the only general-purpose one that I have found.

I would really be happy if the fine folks here at StackExchange made an OpenID Connect IDP similar to what they have for the old OpenID 2 one, found here: https://openid.stackexchange.com/ . I think that could really help the adoption of this new and far better login protocol.

Comment: "far better" might be reaching, considering it requires getting a secret key from every provider which is *incredibly* inconvenient in comparison to OpenID 2. But since the API now already handles OAuth authentication anyway, adding OpenID Connect on Stack Exchange's end would probably not be too much extra effort.

Comment: @JakeFeasal: SQLFiddle is awesome and you are a legend :)